# Strange escape_javascript behavior in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

After I call the ajax method, the escape_javascript function spits out `</div> </div> </div>` for each item being rendered. I've checked all my closing tags, two and three times over, and I can't find an error.  Is the formbuilder instantiated properly?

controller method

```
  def add_new_plan
    new_plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id)

    CustomerPlan.create(...)

    # Pass a form builder to the nested form
    @f = ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder.new(:customer, @customer, view_context, {})

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

js.erb

```
$("#customerPlan").html(
  '<%= j( render("plan_tab1", f: @f) ) %>'
);
```

A mock sample of the html

```
<div>
  <div>
    form collection loop
      all form elements should be contained here
  </div>
  but the FormBuilder is outputting hidden fields here
</div>
```

the hidden fields are rendered altogether, not in their respective form iterations. (Note that the quotation marks in the inspector are not visible on the rendered page.)

[image: screenshot of chrome inspection]

Answer (score 0):

I was updating a form within another form. Converted to the use of two separate forms, linking with a single update button via JS.  The problem was that the first form `<% end %>` tag was still open after the ajax call.